# Using Div to submit value for Form

Tags: html, forms, paypal

I have a form that I use to link to a specific paypal page. It uses hidden fields to generate the page.

Here is the original form:

```
<form class="paypal-form" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="K2D7T7AWDFWT8">
  <input type="image" src="/images/logos/donate/paypal.svg" border="0" name="submit">
</form>
```

However, I would like to have the submit to work on when a div is clicked, instead of an image. I've tried putting the name="submit" on the div, instead of the image, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<form class="paypal-form" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="K2D7T7AWDFWT8">
  <div name="submit">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span>
    <span class="donate-text">Donate</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Any ideas on how to do this? All help greatly appreciated....

Comment: Should it be with input tag and type=submit ?   Or do you want to share your javascript?

Comment: in the original is it on an input tag with name ="submit". But I want to submit when I click any part of a div. I'm not using any javascript on this particular bit.

Comment: I don't think that the name=submit is doing the magic. There is js behind.. Otherwise you might use type=submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came to was to create a hidden form like this:

```
<form id="paypal-form" class="paypal-form" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="{{paypal_id}}">
</form>
```

And then place an ng-click (i'm using angularjs) on the div which then calls the submit on this hidden form like so:

```
document.getElementById('paypal-form').submit();
```

This does the trick nicely. A little hacky but.....

Answer (score 0):

name="submit" is not equal with type = "submit"
instead of writing

```
<form class="paypal-form" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="K2D7T7AWDFWT8">
  <div name="submit">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span>
    <span class="donate-text">Donate</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

I think you should write:

```
<form class="paypal-form" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="K2D7T7AWDFWT8">
  <div>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span>
    <span class="donate-text"><button type="submit">Donate</button></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Hanslen, I don't want to use a button saying Donate - I want the entire div to be 'clickable' and perform the action of loading the paypal page. T

Comment: But I think the type="submit" cannot be used in the div class, also, the action you perform for div I think can also be performed in button as well. Why don't you use button?

Answer (score 0):

Just style  a submit instead of div like:

```
input[type="submit"]{width:100px;height:35px;background:red;border:1px solid #000;} etc.
```